# How to calculate the new $X$ and $Y $ position of an object after changing its size?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

I have some objects that will be positioned in certain $X$ and $Y$ coordinates and that will start with a size of $40\times60$ at an angle of $15^\circ$.

I need to change the size of these objects to $200\times200$ for example, with this the $X$ and $Y$ coordinates will change, it is important that the objects do not collide and respect the angle, and if there is a Gap this must be respected as well.

I included some examples of how the objects will be initially, and a gif showing that after changing the size they occupy a new $X$ and $Y$ position and do not collide. I made these examples using Figma software to facilitate the explanation.

I need to calculate the new $X$ and $Y$ coordinates of the objects dynamically, respecting the criteria above.

Pictures examples:
[image]
[image]

Comment: First, choose a point that you don't want to move - the upper left corner of the selected box in your example. Call it $(x_0, y_0)$. And let $r$ be the ratio of the new size to the old size. Then every other point $(x,y)$ transforms to $$(x_0 + r(x - x_0), y_0 + r(y - y_0))$$